# Is it possible in git to just push 4 out of 5 commits?

Tags: git, push, commit, partial

I have total five commits in my local git repo. Out of five commits I want to push 4 commits and not push the last commit is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use refspec's:

```
git push origin HEAD^:master
```

Comment: what does :master mean? the remote master branch?

Comment: @Smrita, yes.. it's remote branch. And `orgin` is remote repository, `HEAD^` is reference for commits before last on HEAD.

Comment: So to push from development branch to development remote branch I am suppose to execute the following command aint I?  git push origin HEAD^:development

Comment: @Smrita, yes. or  `git push origin development^:development` :)

Comment: @Smrita, Also you can experiment on local branch as target instead of real remote repository - by specifying dot('.') as remote repository name. like this `git push . HEAD^:RefspecTests`. RefspecTests is branch name on current repository :)

Comment: @Smrita, np, Git is awesome! :)